# Pass from a view controller to another programmatically iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller

i'm trying to pass from a view controller to another programmatically when i get Facebook datas, is there a way to do that?
by using my method the app crashes and in log i have that:

> 2015-07-16 13:16:14.125 LoginSampleFB[1059:60b] Warning: Attempt to
>   present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy! 2015-07-16
>   13:16:14.129 LoginSampleFB[1059:60b] Exception 'NSRangeException'
>   caught! Reason: 'Cannot remove an observer  for the key path "hidden" from 
>   because it is not registered as an observer.' 2015-07-16 13:16:14.171
>   LoginSampleFB[1059:60b] *** Assertion failure in -[UIWindowController
>   transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:animation:],
>   /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2935.137/UIWindowController.m:223 2015-07-16
>   13:16:14.172 LoginSampleFB[1059:60b] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   'Attempting to begin a modal transition from  to  while a
>   transition is already in progress. Wait for
>   viewDidAppear/viewDidDisappear to know the current transition has
>   completed'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x185e6ef50 0x1923781fc 0x185e6ee10 0x1869a6db4 0x188f2e5b8 0x188f2da9c 0x1000fabb8 0x1869e42d0
>   0x185e2f554 0x185e2f1c4 0x185e2ceec 0x185d6dc20 0x18ba55c0c
>   0x188e9efdc 0x1000fded8 0x19296baa0) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException

this is the code :

```
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {

    NSString *userName = user.name;
    userName = [userName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
    NSString *userNameOk = userName;
    NSString *userId = [user id];
    NSString *userEmail = [user objectForKey:@"email"];

    NSString *label_name = user.name;
    _profilePicture.profileID = ((dashBoardViewController*)self.tabBarController).id;
    _profilePicture.layer.cornerRadius = _profilePicture.frame.size.width / 2;
    _profilePicture.clipsToBounds = YES;
    _profilePicture.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
    _profilePicture.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;

    //self.lblEmail.text = [user objectForKey:@"email"];

    ((dashBoardViewController*)self.tabBarController).first_name = userNameOk;
    ((dashBoardViewController*)self.tabBarController).id = userId;

    dashBoardViewController *dashBoardViewController =     [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"dashBoardViewController"];
    dashBoardViewController.first_name = userNameOk;
    dashBoardViewController.label_name= userName;
    dashBoardViewController.id = userId;
    dashBoardViewController.userEmail = userEmail;
    [self presentModalViewController:dashBoardViewController animated:YES];

   }
```

**EDIT**

THIS IS FULL CODE

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "dashBoardViewController.h"
#import "BFPaperTabBarController.h"
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>


@interface ViewController ()



@end

@implementation ViewController



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    self.loginButton.delegate = self;
    self.loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"publish_actions"];
     self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


/*-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

      dashBoardViewController *dashBoardViewController =     [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"dashBoardViewController"];

   NSString *USR = ((dashBoardViewController*)self.tabBarController).first_name;
     NSLog(USR);
    if (USR != @"0") {

        NSLog(USR);
        NSLog(@"USR DIVERSO DA 0");

        [self presentModalViewController:dashBoardViewController animated:YES];
    }

}*/

- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {

    NSString *userName = user.name;
    userName = [userName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
    NSString *userNameOk = userName;
    NSString *userId = [user id];
    NSString *userEmail = [user objectForKey:@"email"];

    NSString *label_name = user.name;
    _profilePicture.profileID = ((dashBoardViewController*)self.tabBarController).id;
    _profilePicture.layer.cornerRadius = _profilePicture.frame.size.width / 2;
    _profilePicture.clipsToBounds = YES;
    _profilePicture.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
    _profilePicture.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;

    //self.lblEmail.text = [user objectForKey:@"email"];

    ((dashBoardViewController*)self.tabBarController).first_name = userNameOk;
    ((dashBoardViewController*)self.tabBarController).id = userId;

    dashBoardViewController *dashBoardViewController =     [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"dashBoardViewController"];
    dashBoardViewController.first_name = userNameOk;
    dashBoardViewController.label_name= userName;
    dashBoardViewController.id = userId;
    dashBoardViewController.userEmail = userEmail;
    [self presentModalViewController:dashBoardViewController animated:YES];

   }


-(void)loginView:(FBLoginView *)loginView handleError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

-(IBAction)Skip:(id)sender{

    NSString *userName = @"0";
    NSString *userNameOk = userName;
    NSString *userId = @"0";
    NSString *userEmail = @"0";

    NSString *label_name = @"Loggati";
    _profilePicture.profileID = ((dashBoardViewController*)self.tabBarController).id;
    _profilePicture.layer.cornerRadius = _profilePicture.frame.size.width / 2;
    _profilePicture.clipsToBounds = YES;
    _profilePicture.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
    _profilePicture.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;

    //self.lblEmail.text = [user objectForKey:@"email"];

    ((dashBoardViewController*)self.tabBarController).first_name = userNameOk;
    ((dashBoardViewController*)self.tabBarController).id = userId;

    dashBoardViewController *dashBoardViewController =     [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"dashBoardViewController"];
    dashBoardViewController.first_name = userNameOk;
    dashBoardViewController.label_name= userName;
    dashBoardViewController.id = userId;
    dashBoardViewController.userEmail = userEmail;
    [self presentModalViewController:dashBoardViewController animated:YES];

}

@end
```

Comment: why are you setting the first_name  and id property of dashboardController two times? also, class names should always begin with a capital letter (instance names should be camel case).

Comment: It's hard to tell without more code, but is this method is executing while a view controller is being dismissed?

Comment: Edited correctly @khalafnt